# Entity Framework overwrites a foreign key from another record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This is just an example so you can understand, this is a system with people and their favorite books.

This is what the models look like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> favBooks { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is if I add a book and 2 people and both have this as a FAV book, then one person is overwritten.

```
Book mathForDummies = new Book()
{
     Name = "Math for Dummies",
     PageCount = 457
};
            
_db.book.Add(mathForDummies);
_db.SaveChanges();

Person lena = new Person()
{
     Name = "Lena",
     favBooks = new List<Book>
     {
          mathForDummies
     }
};

Person max = new Person()
{
     Name = "Max",
     favBooks = new List<Book>
     {
          mathForDummies
     }
};
            
_db.person.Add(lena);
_db.person.Add(max);

_db.SaveChanges();
```

In this case, both have this book, but max overwrites lena.

[image: person-table]
[image: book-table]

**Is there a better way, or am I overlooking something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with Entity Framework itself, but with your database schema: your list is a n-to-one (or many-to-one) relationship and you need a n-to-n (or many-to-many).

Since `book` table has only one `PersonId` column (maybe it has a different name), each book can only be associated with one person at a time. To create a n-to-n relationship, you'll need a join table (that have `BookId` and `PersonId` columns).

Look [this link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration) to see how to configure it.

Comment: Yes, I realize that about the relationship. And the database (schema) was generated by EF. What also surprises me. But I'll have a look at your link, I'll get back to you later if necessary.

Comment: Yes, I have one more question. Do you know randomly. Which include or so I have to use so that my book is not a null? 

https://prnt.sc/MYkFXBqHPV5Z

Comment: @Schecher_1, you can configure the schema generated by EF using the Fluent API. One way to set a column as not null is through the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext`. See more on https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/isrequired-method.